# SBT ScalaTest not showing any error details

Tags: scala, sbt

I am running test cases after change code in business logic. I run test case, but it failing by simply saying NullPoinerException. But it not showing any detais about the issue. It is that:

```
> it:testOnly com.company.project.Module.write.AlertModuleSpraySpec -F

[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last project-Module-read/it:testOnly for the full output.
[error] Could not run test com.company.project.Module.write.AlertModuleSpraySpec: java.lang.NullPointerException
[info] Run completed in 1 second, 973 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[error] Error during tests:
[error]         com.company.project.Module.write.AlertModuleSpraySpec
[error] (project-Module-read/it:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 28 Nov, 2016 2:04:45 PM
```

Comment: have you tried the suggestion? `[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last project-Module-read/it:testOnly for the full output.`

Comment: I read that line, but I am not able to understand what change I have to do in previous command executed.

Comment: @SriManga, you need to run the following command in SBT after encountering this error to get the full output of why your tests won't run: `last project-Module-read/it:testOnly`